# Find minimum start date that intersects a set date in a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to pick the minimum date in a range that intersects a set date:

Let's say my set date is today: `11/19/2019`
Given the below dates, I need to find the minimum start date of the event that intersects today.
In this case this would be `11/12/2019`.

```
| StartDate  | EndDate    |  
| -----------| -----------|    
| 11/19/2019 | 11/20/2019 | 
| 11/01/2019 | 11/18/2019 |
| 11/14/2019 | 11/19/2019 |
| 11/17/2019 | 11/21/2019 |
| 11/12/2019 | 11/23/2019 |
| 11/18/2019 | 11/24/2019 |
| 11/13/2019 | 11/27/2019 |
```

Here's my fiddle attempt:
https://jsfiddle.net/89shcxty/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your code; firstly you are not accessing the actual `start` and `end` values from within the objects in `overlappedRanges`, and you are also not checking whether the range actually overlaps today. This should do what you want. Note that I have also modified the code to return `null` if there were *no* ranges that overlap today; you may want to check for that return value.

```js
var overlappedRanges = [{
  start: '11/19/2019',
  end: '11/20/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/01/2019',
  end: '11/18/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/14/2019',
  end: '11/19/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/17/2019',
  end: '11/21/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/12/2019',
  end: '11/23/2019'
}, {
  start: '11/18/2019',
  end: '11/24/2019'
}];

function min_start_date(all_dates) {
  min_dt = null;
  today = new Date();
  all_dates.forEach(function(v) {
    let s = new Date(v.start);
    let e = new Date(v.end);
    if (s > today || e < today) return;
    if (min_dt === null || s < new Date(min_dt)) {
      min_dt = v.start;
    }
  });
  return min_dt;
}

$('#overlapped').text(min_start_date(overlappedRanges));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="overlapped" style="color: red;"></span>
<br>
<span id="notOverlapped" style="color: green;"></span>
```